# Way to not define much variables in Perl?

Tags: perl, curl

I'm asking about most simple way to

1. Get www content (with curl I think)
2. Search and replace text with tree regular expression (`s/a/b/;` and s/as/da' etc)

Must I define variables every time when I want use a Perl command? In bash I piped the output from `curl`:

```
curl www.google.pl | sed 's/a/b'
```

I want to omit of these `$dupa` lines

```perl
$#!/usr/bin/perl

$dupa = `curl -s https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/allPrices`;

$dupa =~ s/"},\{"/\n/g;
$dupa =~ s/":"/=/g;
$dupa =~ s/","/\n/g;
$dupa =~ s/\[{"//g;

print $dupa;
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do overall?

Comment: Download webfile, replace strings from this file  (which will be values for Perls variables) , and write values to variables.

Comment: I mean omit of these $dupa lines:
$`#!/usr/bin/perl 
$dupa=``curl -s https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/allPrices``;
$dupa =~ s/"},\{"/\n/g; 
$dupa =~ s/":"/=/g;
$dupa =~ s/","/\n/g; 
$dupa =~ s/\[{"//g;
print $dupa;`

Comment: Don't ask your question in the comments. If there's something that belongs in your question, put it there.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to write your own JSON parser...

Comment: What is a *"tree regular expression"*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Always [`use strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) in Perl code. No exceptions!
2. Don't shell out to `curl` to make an HTTP request. Use a Perl module like [`LWP::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Simple).
3. The data you are downloading is JSON. Don't manipulate it as a string; use a JSON parser, like [`JSON::XS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::XS), to convert it to a data structure.

Here's a start:

```
use strict;
use LWP::Simple qw( get );
use JSON::XS qw( decode_json );
use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );

my $data = decode_json(get("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/allPrices"));

print Dumper($data);
```

You can now manipulate the data structure in the `$data` variable; for instance:

```
for my $item (@$data) {
    print "$item->{symbol} : $item->{price}\n";
}
```